# PDF Acrofields convert to json object

Tags: java, json, pdf, acrofields

I'm trying to find a solution for my problem for days now, but I haven't found a solid one still. My problem is that I want to convert the AcroFields from my Editable PDF form and convert them into a JsonObject using java and gson.

The format of naming the Keys of the Acrofields would be something like the one used by jQuery.serializeJSON().

Ex. student[address][0][street_address]

and it will convert it to :

```
"student":{
    "address" : [
        {
            "street_address" : "street 123"
        }
    ]

}
```

What my plan is to put all the Acrofield on Map and then using the naming convention, convert them into a JsonObject.

I already have a working one like this but using html form and jquery.serializeJSON, however I also have a requirement where the data comes from the PDF.

Is this possible?

Thank you